# Does `wil::com_ptr` overload operator &, aka "address of"?

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I found this code snippet [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2environment?view=webview2-1.0.1072.54#createwebresourceresponse).

```
wil::com_ptr<IStream> stream;
CHECK_FAILURE(SHCreateStreamOnFileEx(
    L"assets/EdgeWebView2-80.jpg", STGM_READ, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    FALSE, nullptr, &stream));
```

According to [the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatestreamonfileex) of `SHCreateStreamOnFileEx`, the type of the last argument is supposed to be `IStream **`. However the code snippet passes a `wil::com_ptr<IStream> *` to the function instead of a `IStream **`. I'm wondering how it works. Does `wil::com_ptr<IStream>` overload operator `&` (aka "address of")?

By the way, I cannot find the online manual of `wil::com_ptr`. Is it the same as [winrt::com_ptr struct template (C++/WinRT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/com-ptr)? Thanks.

Comment: [`wil::com_ptr` documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/wiki/WinRT-and-COM-wrappers). You could also just [peek at the source code](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/blob/f9284c19c9873664978b873b8858d7dfacc6af1e/include/wil/com.h#L411).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Windows Implementation Libraries (WIL)](https://github.com/microsoft/wil) has its documentation published through its repository's [wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/wiki). The `wil::com_ptr_t` class template<sup>1</sup> is described on the [WinRT and COM wrappers](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/wiki/WinRT-and-COM-wrappers) page.

The section on [Object management methods](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/wiki/WinRT-and-COM-wrappers#object-management-methods) lists three class members that allow clients to get the address of the stored interface pointer:

> - `T** addressof()`
>   Returns the address of the internal pointer without releasing the current COM object. Do not use this for `_Out_` parameters<sup>2</sup> because it will leak the current COM object. For `_Out_` parameters, use the `&` operator, which releases the current COM object before returning the address.
> - `T** put()`
>   Releases the current COM object and returns the address of the internal pointer. Use this method when passing the `com_ptr_t` as a `_Out_` parameter.
> - `T** operator&()`
>   Same as `put()`.

So to answer the literal question: Yes, `wil::com_ptr_t` [does overload](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/blob/f9284c19c9873664978b873b8858d7dfacc6af1e/include/wil/com.h#L411-L414) `operator&()` to return the address of the internal interface pointer after doing some housekeeping.

`wil::com_ptr_t` is unrelated to the [`winrt::com_ptr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/com-ptr) class template<sup>3</sup>, part of the [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt) library. Neither of them are related to ATL's [`CComPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomptr-class) or Visual Studio's [`_com_ptr_t`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-ptr-t-class). Those are the four official implementations, and while all of them have the same goal of automating lifetime management of COM objects they are subtly different in their implementations, with surprising consequences<sup>4</sup>.

The differences are in the following areas:

- Constructors with an interface pointer argument

  Implementations get to choose whether they assume ownership of the passed in interface pointer, or model shared ownership leaving the caller with the responsibility of `Release()`-ing the incoming interface pointer.
- Assignment operators accepting an interface pointer

  Same as above concerning the incoming pointer, with the added twist of having to handle the case where the instance is already holding an interface pointer. Implementations can:

  - Silently drop the currently held interface pointer (the fact that this is a bug doesn't mean that you won't see it)
  - Silently `Release()` the current interface prior to assigning the incoming interface pointer
  - Throw an exception in case the instance is holding an interface pointer
- Retrieving the address of the raw interface pointer

  Similar to the assignment above, the case where the smart pointer instance is already holding an interface needs to be handled, one way or another:

  - Silently drop the stored interface (e.g. `addressof()`)
  - Silently `Release()` the current interface (e.g. `put()`)
  - Throw an exception in case the stored pointer is not a `nullptr`

If you decide to use a COM smart pointer implementation, make sure you have a firm grasp on its semantics. The same literal piece of C++ code will potentially behave differently depending on the library in use.

---

<sup>1</sup> *`wil::com_ptr` is an [alias template](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/blob/f9284c19c9873664978b873b8858d7dfacc6af1e/include/wil/com.h#L902-L906) for `wil::com_ptr_t` with the `err_policy` template argument set to `err_exception_policy`.*

<sup>2</sup> *The snippet in the question could have safely passed `stream.addressof()` even though `ppstm` is marked as an `_Out_` parameter. I'm guessing that the author used `operator&()` instead for consistency, readability, and maintainability.*

<sup>3</sup> *While the WIL and C++/WinRT are independent libraries they can interoperate with surprisingly [little effort](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/wiki/WIL-and-C---WinRT-together).*

<sup>4</sup> *[We're using a smart pointer, so we can't possibly be the source of the leak](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091119-00/?p=15963)*